# SQL Table Structure. Set values and general values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set up a application for scheduling and minuting meetings at work. There are a number of set meeting types but I also want to have a general meeting type that the user can generate as they please. 
I am struggling with designing the correct table structure. I have as follows

### tblMeeting

```
Meeting
MTID
ProjectID
MeetingType
DateTime
```

### tblMeetType

```
MTYID
MeetingType
```

When setting up the meeting, the user selects the meeting type from a drop down list populated from the tblMeettype table. If they select a general meeting i.e MTYID = 6 then they should provide a meeting name. If they select anything else from the list, the name is provided from MeetingType

How do I store this variable meeting name in a database and tie it back to the meeting table so that a user can list all meetings associated with a project?

Is the best option to add the variable meeting names to the meeting type table and then restrict the drop down menu to a specific list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let users create new meetingType when they want and save that new type (new ID, new name) to the tblMeetType like other types. And in this case, we don't need to save the "general" type, just provide options for users create new type.

Comment: Thanks. to make the dropdown list dynamic, should I add a Boolean to this table in order to decide if it appears in the list or not?

Comment: Why do you want to hide some types from the list? If that you can add a column name "Visible" as boolean and just display the one that have Visible = true.

Comment: It's because there are set meeting type that have to be used, but a user could also add a unspecified meeting which would not appear in the list.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a text field (`MeetingName`) to your meeting table, which gets filled in if they select `general meeting (MTYID = 6)`, this is just used to reflect a custom meeting name.

If they select any other meeting type, you just leave this field empty. You can copy over the other meeting types into this field if required, but it would be just as simple to look up that information in a query.